# Dynamics CRM 2011 Online, CrmSvcUtil, Proxy server authentication failing

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Trying to write a [plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695782.aspx) for Dynamics CRM 2011 Online.

The first step is to use CrmSvcUtil to generate the code for the entity classes.

I think I've got the CrmSvcUtil parameters right (see below) but when I run it I get:

> Exiting program with exception: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl'.
>   Enable tracing and view the trace files for more information.

Enabling tracing (via the CrmSvcUtil.exe.config) reveals this error:

> ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: 
>       (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.
>       MetadataLocationRetriever.DownloadMetadata(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
>   etc ...

This makes sense because the network I am on has a proxy server that requires my network username/password to get to the internet. Naturally, this username/password is different to the Dynamics CRM one.

So, how do I get CrmSvcUtil to pass the right username/password to the proxy?

Here's the config file that I'm using with CrmSvcUtil:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="url" value="https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"/>
    <add key="codeCustomization" value="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration"/>
    <add key="out" value="XRM\Xrm.cs"/>
    <add key="namespace" value="Xrm"/>
    <add key="username" value="myusername@fordynamics.com"/>
    <add key="password" value="mydynamicspassword"/>
    <add key="deviceid" value="my device ID"/>
    <add key="devicepassword" value="my device password"/>
    <add key="servicecontextname" value="XrmServiceContext" />
    <add key="servicecontextprefix" value="Xrm" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="configConsoleListener"
        type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener">
          <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"
          initializeData="Error" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha! I think I cracked it.

I added the following to the CrmSvcUtil.exe.config file:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://proxyaddress:port" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

I no longer get the "proxy authentication" error.

(I am getting a different errors, but its about missing assemblies so I think I can probably figure that out ....)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and my problem was the firewall blocking outgoing connections from CrmSvcUtil!